# How to speed up Apple Photos Faces Scan?

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I am in the process of converting from Google Photos to Apple Photos. This is what I have done :

1. Downloaded all Google Photos with gdrive
2. Imported all photos on my macbookpro to Apple Photos
3. 20k Photos and 500 videos are imported and uploaded to iCloud
4. Optimise storage is deselected

Now, for all that time people scanning is running but it is ultra slow. It scanned 2500 photos during 4 days. I tried everything, computer is always on power, left running over night, photos running and not running, restarted computer and everything, but the process is still slow. Sometimes I see process "photoanalysisid" taking up to 80% CPU but usually it is 0%. How can I speed this thing up?

Comment: You can check out this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381795/361949)